# I am issues with proving the following problem: $f^{-1}(f(A)) ⊃ A$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am unsure as to where to start with this problem. The way I read it is that $f^{-1}(f(A)) ⊃ A$ means that $A$ is a subset of the preimage of the image of $A$. But I am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the intended meaning is what you're thinking.

Now, an element $x$ belongs to $f^{-1}(B)$ if and only if $f(x)\in B$. Take $a\in A$: can you say that $f(a)\in f(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Take an element $a\in A$ and use the definition of the pre-image to show it belongs to $f^{-1}\bigl(f(A)\bigr)$.