# problem with the following proof related to basic set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The author of the question being raised in [Proving that $C$ is a subset of $f^{-1}[f(C)]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347880/proving-that-c-is-a-subset-of-f-1fc/2600867#2600867) received some similar proofs. I can follow them but there's something I don't understand.

It's probably a stupid question, but could someone explain me why $f(x)$ should be defined for all $x$? Like when we have $F=[(0,1)]$ on $X=[0,2]$ then $F^{-1}(F(\{0,2\}))=F^{-1}(\{1\})=\{0\}$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: [Welcome to math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6348/290189) Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is defined where ever it's defined. However, talking about the image of a set $S$ under $f$ only makes sense if $f$ is defined on $S$. If you restrict $f$ to $S$ you have equality: $$S=f^{-1}(f(S)).$$
Now, if you look at $f:T\longrightarrow M$, where $M$ and $T$ are sets and $S\subset T$, you might have some $s\in f(S)$ with $f(t)=s$ where $t\in T\setminus S$ and thus $t\in f^{-1}(f(S))$, but $t\not\in S$, so you get inclusion:
$$S\subseteq f^{-1}(f(S)).$$
Does this help?