# f(X ∩ Y) = f(X) ∩ f(Y) for all non empty subsets X and Y of A, given f:A→B is 1-1?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

> Let A and B be nonempty sets and f:A→B be a 1-1 function. Then f(X ∩
>   Y) = f(X) ∩ f(Y) for all non empty subsets X and Y of A.

I believe this statement is true?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of _ii)_ of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/435900/11994.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:A\to B$ is not one-one, we can find $x,y$ for which $x\neq y$ yet $z=f(x)=f(y)$. Consider $X=\{x\}$ and $Y=\{y\}$. The converse is also true: if $f(X)\cap f(Y)=f(X\cap Y)$ for any $X,Y$ then $f$ is one-one.

Comment: It must also be a one to one correspondence, correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is alway true that $f\left(X\cap Y\right)\subset f\left(X\right)\cap f\left(Y\right)$.
If $z\in f\left(X\right)\cap f\left(Y\right)$ then $z=f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)$
for some $x\in X$ and some $y\in Y$. If $f$ is injective then this
leads to $x=y\in X\cap Y$, hence $z=f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)\in f\left(X\cap Y\right)$.
So then also $f\left(X\right)\cap f\left(Y\right)\subset f\left(X\cap Y\right)$
and consequently $f\left(X\right)\cap f\left(Y\right)=f\left(X\cap Y\right)$.

The sets do not have to be non-empty to have this property.