# The name of the book?

Tags: reference-request

Please, can anyone tell me the name of the book from which the author took the screen?

Image: [proof on set theory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B3PD.jpg)

the full answer is here;
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1157332/592926

I have already tried to find out what is the name of this book, but I failed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need that specific book? There are alot of books on set theory.

Comment: Jack M, thanks for your reply. I just tried to find out the book with a lot of examples and expalantions (if there will be a manual guide to it, then it will be perfect). And explanation on this screen seemed to me really exhaustive, so I decided to figure out what is the name of this book.